# How do I convert OS coordinates (X and Y) to longitude and latitude coordinates?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

How do I convert OS coordinates (X and Y) - Eastings and Northings to longitude and latitude coordinates? For example X and Y below

X (Eastings): 347904

Y (Northings): 287484

Comment: It's complicated! Check this link: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM

Comment: I don't think it's UTM. It's OS X (Eastings) and OS Y (Northings)

Answer (score 0):

It just a transverse Mercator projection.  The library [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sf.net) (written
by me) has a class [OSGB](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/classGeographicLib_1_1OSGB.html) which converts eastings + northings to latitude + longitude (and also deals with OS grid references).  If you want to know how to calculate the transverse Mercator projection accurately, see [Transverse Mercator with an accuracy of a few nanometers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00190-011-0445-3) (a preprint is available [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.1417)).